# Conditional probabilities for discrete random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two (dependent) non-negative discrete random variables. Assume that these variables can take the following values: $0$, $1$ and $2$.

I have some questions regarding conditional probabilities:

1) Is the following relation correct: $$P(X>0 \mid Y \ge 0)=P(X>0 \mid Y=0)+P(X>0 \mid Y=1)+P(X>0 \mid Y=2)$$ 
If it is not the case, how can we express $P(X>0 \mid Y \ge 0)$ ?

2) Can we claim that $P(X>0 \mid Y \ge 0) \ge P(X>0 \mid Y > 0)$ ? if so, why ?

3) For general non-negative random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$ (discrete or continuous), what is the relation between $P(X>0 \mid Y \ge 0, Z<t)$ and $P(X>0 \mid Y \ge 0, Z \ge t)$, for some constant $t >0$.
In other words, what is the relation between $P( Y \ge 0, Z<t \mid X>0 )$ and $P( Y \ge 0, Z \ge t \mid X >0 )$ ?

Comment: do you mean non-negative (instead of positive)?

Comment: @drhab you are correct. I have edited the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathsf{Q1}.$ No. It is not correct. In fact, since $Y$ takes values from $\{0, 1, 2\}$, $Y \geq 0$ gives no information for $X$. Therefore,
$$
\Pr(X > 0 \mid Y \geq 0) = \Pr(X > 0)
$$
However, we have by law of total probability
$$
\Pr( X>0, Y \geq 0) = \Pr(X > 0, Y = 0) + \Pr(X > 0, Y = 1) + \Pr(X > 0, Y = 2)
$$
but $\Pr(X > 0, Y \geq 0)$ is different from $\Pr(X > 0 \mid Y \geq 0)$.

$\mathsf{Q2}.$ No. It depends. An example would be $X = Y$ and
$$
X = \begin{cases}
0 &\text{with probability } 1 / 3 \\
1 & \text{with probability } 1/ 3 \\
2 & \text{with probability } 1/ 3
\end{cases}
$$
In this example,
$$
\Pr( X> 0 \mid Y \geq 0) = \frac{2}{3} \quad\text{and}\quad\Pr(X > 0 \mid Y > 0) = 1
$$

$\mathsf{Q3}.$ We have 
$$
\Pr(Y \geq 0, Z < t \mid X > 0) + \Pr(Y \geq 0, Z \geq t \mid X > 0) = \Pr(Y \geq 0 \mid X > 0)
$$

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question and provide an answer (if possible): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236671/conditional-probability-containing-two-random-variables/2236970?noredirect=1#comment4599702_2236970