# Conditional probability containing two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

-Define $X$ and $X_1$ to be two dependent non-negative random variables.
Specifically, $X_1$ depends on two (continuous) random variables, termed $X_1^{(1)}$ and $X_1^{(2)}$, and $X$ depends on these two random variables in addition to a third one, termed $X^{(3)}$ (which is also continous r.v.).
-In a similar fashion, we define $Y$ and $Y_1$ to be two dependent non-negative random variables:   $Y_1$ depends on $Y_1^{(1)}$ and $Y_1^{(2)}$, and $Y$ depends on $Y_1^{(1)}$, $Y_1^{(2)}$ and $X^{(3)}$.
-Note that $X$ and $Y$ are dependent on each other; they both depends on the same random variable $X^{(3)}$. We also note that $X_1$ is independent of $Y$, and $Y_1$ is independent of $X$.
-Let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be some non-negative constant values that the random variables can take.

Based on the above, is the following relation correct ? if so, how can we prove it ?
$$P(X_1=a,Y_1=b \mid X=c,Y=d)= P(X_1=a \mid X=c) P(Y_1=b \mid Y=d)$$

*Attempt:*
I tried to use Bayes' theorem: 
$$P(X_1=a,Y_1=b \mid X=c,Y=d)= \frac{P(X_1=a, X=c, Y_1=b, Y=d)}{P(X=c,Y=d)}$$
But how to proceed from here? How to decompose $P(X_1=a, X=c, Y_1=b, Y=d)$ ?

I also tried to use the following relation (but I cannot prove it analytically):
$P(X_1=a,Y_1=b \mid X=c,Y=d)= P(X_1=a \mid X=c, Y=d) P(Y_1=b \mid X=c,Y=d)$.  But even if this relation is correct, can we claim that $P(X_1=a \mid X=c, Y=d)=P(X_1=a \mid X=c)$ ?

PS: Clearly, $X$, $X_1$, $Y$ and $Y_1$ are discrete random variables. $X_1^{(1)}$, $X_1^{(2)}$, $X^{(3)}$, $Y_1^{(1)}$, $Y_1^{(2)}$ are continuous random variables.

Comment: Again no personal input. Why?

Comment: I have added my attempts. Thank you.

Comment: Not really. Things would start to be non empty if you really added your tries, for example, what is "the expression" that "becomes more complicated". At present you are vaguely describing the spirit of what you tried hence one cannot work on anything solid to answer you.

Comment: The only thing I have added is the Bayes' theorem. The problem is that I am  not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have trouble proving something, you may want to look for a counterexample.

Maybe something like this helps. Say $X_1$, $Y_1$ and $X^{(3)}$ are independent and $X=X_1+[X^{(3)}]$ and $Y=Y_1+[X^{(3)}]$, where $[\_]$ is the greatest integer function.

Then $P(X_1=a,Y_1=b \mid X=c,Y=d)=0$ for $a\neq b+c-d$.

However, you can probably (depending on the distribution) find a combination of numbers $a\neq b +c-d$ for which $P(X_1=a \mid X=c) P(Y_1=b \mid Y=d) \neq 0.$

Comment: $X$ is a discrete random variable, whereas $X^{(3)}$ is a continuous one. How can you suppose that $X=X_1+X^{(3)}$ ?

Comment: Well you didn't state that in the question, so I assumed it is a possibility. I see you edited the question, but still no mention of X being discrete.

Comment: Sorry about that. But I thought it is clear since we know that $P(X=a)=0$ if $X$ is a continuous r.v.

Comment: Ok, I think this minimal edit (to use greatest integer) is enough.